# why doesn't my label show when i run my app in xcode

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I am trying to add a label to my settings page but its not showing when i run my app and i am not sure why this the the following code that i have

```
class SettingsVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Properties

let name: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "name"
    label.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    label.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    return label
}()


//MARK: - Handlers

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    navigationItem.title = "Settings"
    setBarButtons()
    view.addSubview(name)
    name.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
}

func setBarButtons() {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSaveInfo))
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        .font: UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Wide", size: 23)!
    ]
}

@objc func handleSaveInfo() {
    print("Save info")
    
}
```

}

Comment: Try using the view debugger while running.  It will show you the hierarchy and you can check the size and position of your label.

Comment: So it is showing up just not in the screen. when i change the topPadding to like 400 it appears. how would i fix this?

Comment: You can give it a frame when you init it or supply constraints for auto layout.